# Integral coordinates Proof

Tags: coordinate-systems

Nine distinct points with all coordinates integral are selected in the space. Prove that the line segment with ends at certain two of these points contains in its interior a point with all coordinates integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Look at the coordinates modulo $2$ and apply the pigeonhole principle. The point in the interior of the segment will actually be its midpoint.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: 9>2^3, so there must be 2 points in a set with identical coordinates modulo 2.

Comment: @Jebediah: If two integers are both odd or both even, their sum is divisible by $2$, so their midpoint (average) is an integer. You want two points whose coordinates match in parity (oddness/evenness). See also nsg’s comment.